# Fail2Ban Regex Does Not Match

Tags: linux, security, regex, fail2ban

I am unable to get my fail2ban fail regex to get to match to the log entries.

The following is a sample log entry:

```
Failed login attempt {"xForwardedFor":"192.168.0.38","remoteAddress":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0","timestamp":1573556557}
```

This is my configuration:

```
[Definition]
failregex= ^Failed login attempt {\"xForwardedFor\":\"<HOST>\"
ignoreregex =
datepattern = "timestamp":{EPOCH}}$
```

Fail2ban does not return a match while running or when testing with fail2ban-regex as follows.

```
fail2ban-regex 'Failed login attempt {"xForwardedFor":"192.168.0.38","remoteAddress":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0","timestamp":1573556557}' '^Failed login attempt {\"xForwardedFor\":\"<HOST>\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your log file does not begin with timestamps. Based on the [Manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters),

> - **In order for a log line to match your failregex, it actually has to match in two parts: the beginning of the line has to match a timestamp pattern or regex**, and the remainder of the line has to match your failregex. If the failregex is anchored with a leading `^`, then the anchor refers to the start of the remainder of the line, after the timestamp and intervening whitespace.
> - The pattern or regex to match the time stamp is currently not documented, and not available for users to read or set. See Debian bug #491253. This is a problem if your log has a timestamp format that fail2ban doesn't expect, since it will then fail to match any lines. Because of this, you should test any new failregex against a sample log line, as in the examples below, to be sure that it will match. If fail2ban doesn't recognize your log timestamp, then you have two options: either reconfigure your daemon to log with a timestamp in a more common format, such as in the example log line above; or file a bug report asking to have your timestamp format included.

I tried your case in my machine by putting the timestamps in the beginning, Fail2Ban does recognize the pattern.

```
~$ sudo fail2ban-regex '1573556557 Failed login attempt {"xForwardedFor":"192.168.0.38","remoteAddress":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0","timestamp":1573556557}' 'Failed login attempt {\"xForwardedFor\":\"<HOST>'
       
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : Failed login attempt {\"xForwardedFor\":\"<HOST>
Use      single line : 1573556557 Failed login attempt {"xForwardedFor":"...


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] Failed login attempt {\"xForwardedFor\":\"<HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] {^LN-BEG}Epoch
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]
```

Maybe you can modified your log file so that the date & time can be put at the beginning.
I also have another references related with your case:

[Case 1](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2029)

[Case 2](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2463)

Hopefully this helps.